# How to use range::minmax_element on a range::concat buffer with a specific range to be tested

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I can't seem to get `range::minmax_element` working. Some combinations compile and segfault when run, other combinations won't compile. I'd like to know how to solve my problem.

The complications are that I'm running `minmax_element` against a `range::concat` buffer and I need a very specific range of elements to be tested. Here is the code I've developed to simulate my working code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

struct test {
    double price;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timestamp;
};

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::vector<test> v1 = {{1.0, std::chrono::sys_days{1970y / 1 / 1}},
                            {2.0, std::chrono::sys_days{1970y / 1 / 2}},
                            {3.0, std::chrono::sys_days{1970y / 1 / 3}}};
    std::vector<test> v2 = {{}};

    const auto buf = ranges::concat_view(v1, v2);

    const auto lower_tf = 1;
    const auto upper_tf = 5;
    const auto cnum_at_i = 0;

    auto lower_tf_limit = ranges::rbegin(buf);
    auto upper_tf_limit = ranges::rbegin(buf);

    {
        // segfault when running std::minmax_element
        auto [ lower_tf_limit, upper_tf_limit ] = ranges::minmax_element(
            ranges::rbegin(buf) + cnum_at_i + 1,
            ranges::rbegin(buf) + cnum_at_i + 1 + (upper_tf / lower_tf),
                           {}, &test::price);
    }

    if (lower_tf_limit != ranges::rbegin(buf) &&
        upper_tf_limit != ranges::rbegin(buf))
        std::cout << "lower_tf_limit->price = " << lower_tf_limit->price << std::endl;
}
```

I'm aware that the array v2 is empty but that shouldn't affect the view of any of its iterators. I'm also aware the start and end iterators for the `minmax_element` command are passed the end of the buffer, at least in this example. Eventually, v1 will be populated with enough elements for it not to cause a problem but this code isn't shown. I would assume that the default first element is returned to the `lower_tf_limit` and `upper_tf_limit` iterators in this case rather than not compile or segfault. I'm also aware that I'm using some inner `{ }` to limit the scope of the `minmax_element` statement and to simulate my working code. This needs to remain as such.

How do I fix my code, please?

Here's a compiler explorer play area: https://godbolt.org/z/n3qPod6rW

Comment: `buf` has 4 elements in it. You're trying to do `ranges::minmax_element` from elements `1` through `6`... that's running off the end.

Comment: In which case, it should just return `ranges::rend` or `ranges::rbegin`, shouldn't it?

Comment: *"I'm aware that the array v2 is empty"* It is not, it contains a default `test`.

Comment: No. The way that any algorithm works is that if you call `algo(first, last)`, `[first, last)` has to actually be a valid range.

Comment: Ok, I'll adapt my code accordingly but it doesn't explain why my code isn't compiling.

Comment: I can't see the error. What should it be then, please?

Comment: Are you asking me? I already wrote how it should be. It doesn't help with the segfault (since you iterate out of bounds) but at least it will compile.

Comment: Yes I was. Sorry I hadn't seen that you had changed your comment. Thank you. All compiles and runs: https://godbolt.org/z/q4fz9ofWG Thanks all.

Comment: No problem. Why first create two iterators and create two new that you only use to assign to the first two though? Simplified: https://godbolt.org/z/WqsnYcd5E

Comment: It's to simulate my working code. I'm using the `minmax_element` within an if statement so the scope of `lower_tf_limit` and `upper_tf_limit` is limited to that of the if's scope, I need a scope more general.

Comment: @Andrew: You can't use structured binding for that, the new bindings in the inner scope will shadow the outer ones for the duration of the inner scope, but not change the outer scope variables, which will be unshadowed when the inner scope completes. If you need to declare them in an outer scope, and reassign them in an inner scope, use `std::tie` in the inner scope to reassign the original variables in a convenient manner, e.g. `std::tie(lower_tf_limit, upper_tf_limit) = ranges::minmax_element(...)`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Fails to compile with `tie`: https://godbolt.org/z/TeY5T7WPf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until a ranges-v3 answer comes along, here's how you could solve it using `std::minmax_element`:

```cpp
auto lower_tf_limit = ranges::rbegin(buf);
auto upper_tf_limit = ranges::rbegin(buf);

/* some unknown condition goes here */ {
    std::tie(lower_tf_limit, upper_tf_limit) = std::minmax_element(
        ranges::rbegin(buf) + cnum_at_i + 1,
        ranges::rbegin(buf) + cnum_at_i + 1 + (upper_tf / lower_tf),
        [](auto&& t1, auto&& t2) { return t1.price < t2.price; });
}
```

Comment: Either I'm missing the fact that not all the of *ranges-v3* was adopted (as cppreference indicates with its absence of the member functions in the question) or `gcc (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801` doesn't have it yet. It fell over when I tried it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Afaik, not all of ranges-v3 was adopted and what was adopted was partially changed. I'm also not very comfortable with any of them yet, hence my `std::minmax_element` solution :-)